# how can i display a message in the first screen of an android phone?

Tags: android, screen

I have to develop an application that display some information about the possessor of the phone in case of loss. So my first screen must look like this :[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you want to use services in a widget I think.
But for the screen You can simply use xml. Make a table view or Linear Layout will work too. Add the data and display it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it as a widget  and add to android desktop. For appluing it just app corespond intent filter in Android manifest.

```
<receiver android:name="ExampleAppWidgetProvider" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
               android:resource="@xml/example_appwidget_info" />
</receiver>
```